# Как изменять текст в textview через определённый промежуток времени?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, textview

Всем здравствуйте! Надо сделать так, чтобы текст менялся через определённый промежуток времени. Пробовал поставить `Thread.sleep(600);`. Результат: приложение подвисает и текст ставится самый последний (конечный). Пробовал поставить **postdelay** - компилятор выдаёт кучу ошибок. Не знаю как правильно его поставить.
Вот сам код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> spinner1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> spinner2 = new ArrayList<>();
    EditText editText;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
    Spinner mainSpinner;
    Spinner newSpinner;
    Button button;
    int i = 1;
    String CurrentText;
    int width = 0;
    int ran1;
    int ran2;
    int ran3;
    int ran4;
    int ran5;
    int ran6;
    int ran7;
    int ran8;
    String str1;
    String str2;
    String str3;
    String str4;
    String str5;
    String str6;
    String str7;
    String str8;
    String str9;
    String str10;
    boolean block = true;
    Random r = new Random();
    TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        mainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MainSpinner);
        newSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.NewSpinner);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
        final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        width = metrics.widthPixels;

        // адаптер MainSpinner
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner1);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mainSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        // адаптер NewSpinner
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner2);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        newSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    private void initiatePopupWindow() {
        try {
            ran8 = r.nextInt(89999999) + 10000000;
            str1 = String.valueOf(ran8);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.standardscrapyard, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            textview = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textview.setText(str1);
            PopupWindow pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, width, 180, true);
            pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void delay() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View button) {
        CurrentText = (editText.getText().toString());
        if (i == 1) {
            spinner1.add(editText.getText().toString());
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mainSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        } else {
            spinner2.add(editText.getText().toString());
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            newSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
        }
        if (CurrentText.equals("12345")) {
            newSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            i = 2;
        }
        if (CurrentText.equals("2014")) {
            ran7 = r.nextInt(8999999) + 1000000;
            ran6 = r.nextInt(899999) + 100000;
            ran5 = r.nextInt(89999) + 10000;
            ran4 = r.nextInt(8999) + 1000;
            ran3 = r.nextInt(899) + 100;
            ran2 = r.nextInt(89) + 10;
            ran1 = r.nextInt(7) + 2;
            str2 = "0" + (String.valueOf(ran7));
            str3 = "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran6));
            str4 = "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran5));
            str5 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran4));
            str6 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran3));
            str7 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran2));
            str8 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + (String.valueOf(ran1));
            str9 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "1";
            str10 = "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0" + "0";
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Режим помойки включен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            initiatePopupWindow();
            textview.setText(str2);
            delay();
            textview.setText(str3);
            delay();
            textview.setText(str4);
            delay();
            textview.setText(str5);
            delay();
            textview.setText(str6);
            delay();
            textview.setText(str7);
            delay();
            textview.setText(str8);
            delay();
            textview.setText(str9);
            delay();
            textview.setText(str10);
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы `textview` менялось на `str1, str2, str3` и т.д.
Извините, если что-то делаю не так. Просто я новичок в java и много чего не понимаю.
Как правильно поставить `postdelay`, чтобы всё работало корректно и без ошибок? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;
private TextView tv;

private ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
private int counter = 0;

public void onClick()
{
    strings.add("1"); 
    strings.add("2");
    strings.add("3");

    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if(counter==strings.size())
                    {
                        timer.cancel();
                        return;
                    }
                    tv.setText(strings.get(counter));
                    counter++;
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);

}
```

Comment: Теперь вопрос: как завершить таймер при достижении последней строки?

Comment: @HybridTC25, Добавьте счётчик. По его достижении вызовете `timer.cancel()`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Приложение работает, но через каждый промежуток времени выводит в textview: str1, str2, str3 и т.д. пока не дойдёт до str10. А мне надо, чтобы программа выводила значения переменных str1, str2, str3 и т.д. Как это сделать? Вот скриншот кода: [http://s020.radikal.ru/i714/1604/97/731c94b9bf01.png]

Comment: @HybridTC25,  Вам счётчик нужен за пределами таймера. На уровне класса. А в таймере вы его увеличивайте и проверяйте на максимальное значение. По его достижении - выключайте таймер.

Comment: У меня есть идея добавить switch и case. Только не знаю будет ли код работать. Сейчас попробую так сделать.

Comment: @HybridTC25, см. обновлённый ответ

Comment: Написал Ваш код, а приложение теперь выводит в textview: 2, 3, 4, 5 и т.д. А мне надо чтобы каждый раз выводил `textview.setText(str1);` `textview.setText(str2);` `textview.setText(str3);` и т.д. А приложение выводит: `textview.setText("2");` `textview.setText("3");` `textview.setText("4");` и т.д. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: @HybridTC25, ну так замените `"2"` на `str2` - в чём проблема-то?.. 0_о

Comment: какое странное приложение....))

Comment: @ermak0ff, в детстве я примерно так себе представлял делание дыр в пространстве-времени))) Берёшь много цифр, смешиваешь - и вуаля - проход на Марс)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Огромное спасибо! Приложение работает, текст изменяется. Удачи! До свидания!